# C# Loading Excel File Using Interop Unhandled 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Unknown Module

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Attempting to load multiple .xlsx files.  After updating Office versions to 2013 to make sure the .dll was compatible, I'm still getting this error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified.

When attempting to execute the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace SolnName
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //File paths
            string path1 = @"path\file1.xlsx";
            string path2 = @"path\file2.xlsx";

            try
            {
                Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

                Excel.Workbook book1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path1);
                Excel.Worksheet sheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)book1.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                Excel.Workbook book2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path2);
                Excel.Worksheet sheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)book2.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                book1.Close(true, null, null);
                book2.Close(true, null, null);

                xlApp.Quit();

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet1);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet2);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(book1);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(book2);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The plan ultimately is to create pivot tables in a new file based off the data, but I can't even execute opening and closing the files.  The files DO exist at the actual file paths.  All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider whether your error relates to a run-time failure to load your application's dependent assemblies or one of their dependent assemblies. Check out the the Fusion Log: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target Framework was off for the VS Project.